# Destroying a ZFS file system

Tags: 16.04, zfs

Back when I set my server up a couple of years ago, I did some research and decided to go with a zfs file system for the 3 disks I'd be using for my storage.

Overall I've been very happy with it. To start with I just used 3 500gb hard drives I had from old laptops and when I decided to upgrade them, the process of replacement was incredibly easy and I had all 3 disks replaced within a few hours.

But I'm wanting to make a few changes. I want to be able to quickly view the total capacity of the system and how much of it has been used, but when I set it up, I created some separate mount points.

Essentially I have the entire pool mounted as /willzpool, but then within it I have 5 separate folders -
/willzpool/will (my storage)
/willzpool/MrsWill (my wife's storage)
/willzpool/media (a common folder we can both access and also used as a storage for my plex library and downloaded distros/torrents etc)

All 3 are also shared by samba for windows compatibility.

For whatever reason I gave these 3 folders their own mount points of /willzpool/will, /willzpool/MrsWill, /willzpool/media. This means that when I use 'zfs list' I don't really get an exact figure for how much the entire pool is using, it's split down into 4 seperate filesystems.

I also have 2 folders within the main /willzpool of /willzpool/backups (used for an rsync backup of my entire / system minus some folders so I can easily recover if I break something) and /willzpool/nextcloud (used for my nextcloud data folder)
These 2 folders are counted against /willzpool's storage when I run 'zfs list' and I have the backups folder shared by samba too so I can verify it's all working as I want it (only set it up last week) so as far as I can see the seperate mounts for will/MrsWill/media are actually pointless.

If I destroy the mount with zfs destroy, will it delete the contents of the folders or just destroy the mount points, leaving me with my top level /willzpool zfs entry that 'zfs list' will then give me totals for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I think I've answered my own question.

I moved the contents of one of my zfs file systems to a new folder

`mv /willzpool/MrsWill/* /Willzpool/MrsWillbackup`

which emptied the folder. I then created a test file, ran `zfs destroy willzpool/MrsWill` and the MrsWill folder and its contents were gone.

I `mv /willzpool/MrsWillBackup /willzpool/MrsWill` and accessed the folder through a laptop via samba and everything works just as it did before except now the top level zfs `/willzpool/` now references the total size of the data.

For reference, the reason this was helpful is that I'm using conky & webmin to remotely monitor my hdd usage on the server and neither accurately reflect the overall size of the willzpool volume (comprised of 3 disks) when it's broken down into separate file systems)